# Login page in r shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyauthr

In shiny APP I want to add a basic feature where the login details to be shown first and after verification the main dashboard body or tabs to be come into view.

Currently the dashboard main body is enabled and if the user enters details in side bar the main body is populated making login page irrelevant. I am not able to put that check in the tool.

Below is the code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- tibble::tibble(
user = c("user1", "user2"),
password = sapply(c("pass1", "pass2"), sodium::password_store),
permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Hello",tags$li(class = "dropdown", style = "padding: 8px;", 
shinyauthr::logoutUI("logout"))),  
dashboardSidebar(textInput("x","Enter name"),
               textInput("y","Enter last name")),
               
dashboardBody(
# login section
shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),


tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
            tabPanel("Tab_1",textOutput("first_name"),textOutput("last_name")),
            tabPanel("Tab_2"),
            tabPanel("Tab_3")
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
id = "login",
data = user_base,
user_col = user,
pwd_col = password,
sodium_hashed = TRUE,
log_out = reactive(logout_init())
)

# Logout to hide
logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
id = "logout",
active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
)

output$first_name <-  renderText(paste("1st name : ", input$x))
output$last_name <-  renderText(paste("Last name : ",input$y))
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr/blob/master/inst/shiny-examples/shinydashboard/app.R) you can find an example on how to use {shinyauthr} along with {shinydashboard}.